# invalid pointer when returning std::string (so says libc)

Tags: c++, linux, stdstring, g++4.8

I have a member function inside a mmapped-file-consuming class, that looks like this:

```
std::string Data::GetASCIIZ(OFFSET* offsetp) const
{
  char* str = (char*)_buffer + *offsetp;  // _buffer points to mmap'd file
  *offsetp += strlen(str) + 1;
  return std::string(str);
}
```

(the type of 'OFFSET' is unsigned long long)

Its raison d'etre is to (a) return a std::string of the null-terminated C-string that is presumed to exist at offset `*offsetp`, after (b) advancing the value of `*offsetp` past the end of said C-string.

I call this function in numerous situations, without issue.   However, I have recently added a new call to it, that always SIGABRTs in a peculiar way:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/ryan/src/coolapp/out/coolapp: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7eb165c ***
```

The above message is followed by a backtrace (culminating in some code within libc.so.6), and a memory map... both of which are ostensibly useful to me somehow, in debugging this issue.

From debugging with GDB, I've learned that the SIGABRT doesn't actually happen inside my `Data::GetASCIIZ` method quoted above, but rather within the code that calls it during the right side of an assignment.   (So, I presume during the invocation of std::string's copy constructor):

[**EDIT**: updated to dovetail with an expected answer from @WhozCraig]

```
struct stuff
{
  char version;
  std::string sigstring;
  // ...
};

stuff* mystuff = (stuff*)malloc(sizeof(stuff));
// ...
mystuff->sigstring = _data->GetASCIIZ(offsetp);  // SIGABRT HAPPENS AT THIS SCOPE
```

In this particular situation, the C-string at offset `*offsetp` happens to be an empty string, but I've verified that that is not consequential by temporarily modifying `*offsetp` to point to something else from within GDB.

My method is marked `const` because it does not modify any of the internal state of the `Data` object.  I am returning an object that lives on the stack, but I am not doing so by reference, and I expected the copy constructor (in the calling code) to do the right thing before that stack item was destructed.

I have tried rewriting the `GetASCIIZ` method to use an explicit local, but that did not help.

Am I missing something?

In case it is useful, here is the disassembly of the call-during-assignment where this SIGABRT happens.  (The '==>' is at the point of the error.)

```
424         sigstring = _data->GetASCIIZ(offsetp);
   0x0807def1 <+183>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0807def4 <+186>:   mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
   0x0807def7 <+189>:   lea    0x4(%eax),%ecx
   0x0807defa <+192>:   lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
   0x0807defd <+195>:   mov    0x1c(%ebp),%edx
   0x0807df00 <+198>:   mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
   0x0807df04 <+202>:   mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
   0x0807df08 <+206>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0807df0b <+209>:   call   0x809e6ee <Data::GetASCIIZ(unsigned long long*) const>
   0x0807df10 <+214>:   sub    $0x4,%esp
   0x0807df13 <+217>:   mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
   0x0807df16 <+220>:   lea    0x4(%eax),%edx
   0x0807df19 <+223>:   lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
   0x0807df1c <+226>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0807df20 <+230>:   mov    %edx,(%esp)
   0x0807df23 <+233>:   call   0x8049560 <_ZNSsaSEOSs@plt>
   0x0807df28 <+238>:   lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
   0x0807df2b <+241>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
=> 0x0807df2e <+244>:   call   0x80497f0 <_ZNSsD1Ev@plt>
   0x0807e026 <+492>:   lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
   0x0807e029 <+495>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0807e02c <+498>:   call   0x80497f0 <_ZNSsD1Ev@plt>
   0x0807e031 <+503>:   mov    %ebx,%eax
   0x0807e033 <+505>:   jmp    0x807e046 <CoolClass::SpiffyMethod(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long*)+524>
   0x0807e035 <+507>:   mov    %eax,%ebx
```

Comment: How does one *arrive* at said "new call"? Does the `Data` object being purveyed undergo a unintentional copy and violate a [RO3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) situation in doing so? And I'm genuinely curious what you're doing to `sigstring` *prior* to invoking your function. I.e. What is `// ...` ?

Comment: Try something like const string sigstring = _data->Get...

Comment: @WhozCraig By 'new call' I assume you mean this most-recently added call to Data::GetASCIIZ().  No; the address of the Data object is passed into the constructor of the class that ultimately makes this call.  That address is squirreled away inside the `_data` member, and is only ever referenced via `_data`.  So, no copies.  Also:  `//...` just means <some irrelevant code goes here>.  This assignment is the first thing that ever happens to `sigstring`

Comment: @Pradyumna: why?  the method I'm calling doesn't return a const std::string

Comment: are you sure that after that string there is 0 character? Because you have to use terminating zero in c

Comment: I undetstand. My question was, does `//....` do **anything** to/with/around/potentially-overblast-unintentionally `sigstring` ? That variable is obviously used. My concern is you may potentially be invalidly polluting it prior to the assignment, an action which will release its prior content, and in so doing as-polluted reflect as precisely the conundrum you now experience. Debugging *in* to the standard lib for that assignment operator may be warranted.

Comment: @WhozCraig: It does not.  The actual code is:  (1) malloc a struct that includes sigstring and about 10 other fields (2) read the values of each of those fields from the mmap'd file, using _data.  At this point in time, the assignment after my `//...` is the only existing reference in the code to the sigstring member (not counting the struct definition, of course.)

Comment: @WhozCraig: adding to my last comment: the only struct member initialized prior to initializing sigstring is a `char` member, and it is initialized via assignment.  I doubt that corrupts the std::string that follows.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell "malloc a struct that includes sigstring" - stop there. You do **NOT** `malloc` non POD types in C++. You should be using `new` and `delete` for that structure that contains `sigstring`, not `malloc`.

Comment: To add to @WhozCraig's comment, using `malloc` gives you uninitialised memory, and for POD types, that's okay, but other types (including many C++ standard library types) need and expect their constructor to have run. You could use `malloc` followed by placement `new` if you really want to, but there's probably no real benefit in that compared to plain `new`: all you gain is that the result can be used with `realloc` and `free`, and neither of those are appropriate for non-POD objects anyway.

Comment: For me, it may simply be a bug in memory management that happens *before* the problematic code, and that leads in corruption of the memory allocation data. Try running the code with valgrind, it will tell you if there are unallowed writes somewhere in your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig:  that's got to be it.  When I started the struct, the `sigstring` field was originally a `char*`, and all other fields were POD as well.  Then, while writing this code, I changed it to std::string to match the return type of `Data:GetASCIIZ`.   If you want to rewrite your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  (I'll also revise my question to reflect this info.)

Answer (score -1):

Your sample is as follows.

```
std::string Data::GetASCIIZ(OFFSET* offsetp) const
{
  char* str = (char*)_buffer + *offsetp;  // _buffer points to mmap'd file
  *offsetp += strlen(str) + 1;
  return std::string(str);
}
```

Shouldn't the return statement return a **new** STL string?

```
std::string Data::GetASCIIZ(OFFSET* offsetp) const
{
  char* str = (char*)_buffer + *offsetp;  // _buffer points to mmap'd file
  *offsetp += strlen(str) + 1;
  return new std::string(str);
}
```

Comment: No, that would allocate a new std::string on the heap, and result in a memory leak.  My `return std::string(str)` line effectively creates an unnamed local variable solely for the purpose of returning it (by value) to the calling routine, which assigns its value to another string before the former gets destructed.

Comment: Since I haven't made much use of the STL to date, I wasn't sure, and I appreciate the clarification. If I understand what you are saying, returning `std::string(str)` implies the new operator.